# React Native PropTypes has been moved to a separate package

Tags: react-native

I am using

react-native-cli 2.0.1

react-native 0.47.1

react 16.0.0-beta.2

I am a total beginner in react-native and I decided to give it a try to Employee app written by Denislav Ganchev from this article https://mentormate.com/blog/react-native-components/.

But I am getting this error

```
Warning: PropTypes has been moved to a separate package. Accessing React.PropTypes is no longer supported and will be removed completely in React 16. Use the prop-types package on npm instead.
```

Here is the screenshot of the same error

[image]

I see the link in the error in screenshot above pointing to migration but as a complete beginner, I have difficult time figuring what I need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It basically means you need to install the module separately, although it was part of React core module in previous versions.

```
npm install --save prop-types

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

more info [here](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types)

```
// Until 15.4
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
...
React.PropTypes.string.isRequired

// Now
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
...
PropTypes.string.isRequired
```

Comment: yes, that link talks about version of react. How do I find mine?  Sorry, very new to this, I only can find versions of react-native on my machine.  Do you mind elaborating bit, I started with react native just cpl days ago.  Thanks

Comment: if you look inside `package.json` in the `root` folder you can see `react` version

Comment: yup, figured that out, thanks.  Wold you mind providing step by step what to do to resolve issue with PropTypes?  I am new to this.  Much appreciated

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue but my app is still not running for some reason in IOS emulator, it says "to start, edit index.ios.js file".  But I guess that is other issue.  Thanks so much!

Comment: yah, no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

After version 15.5 you have to import PropTypes from prop-types like below:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

//And remove React from "React.PropTypes.string.isRequired"

Component.propTypes = {
text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```