# After migrating code from React Native 0.49 to 0.59 get error '_react.default.PropTypes.bool'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm migrating my code manually from React Native v0.49 to v0.59. When I run the app I'm getting error undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.default.PropTypes.bool'). I'm using typescript in this project. There is some content in FieldValidation.tsx.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Row, Col } from 'native-base';
import { themeService } from '../../Core/Services';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import IconLine from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';

import {
  ModalPicker,
  DatePicker,
  InputLabel,
  Input,
  InputBordered,
  CustomerPicker
} from '../Components';

export default class FieldValidationComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {

render() {
    const { meta: { touched, error } } = this.props;
    switch (this.props.caseType) {
    case 'inline_boxed_date': {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <View style={[this.globalTheme.get('middleV'), { flex: 1 }]}> // Line 300
            {this.props.label}
          </View>
          <View style={[touched && error ? this.formTheme.get('boxedRed') : this.formTheme.get('boxed'), { flex: 1 }]}>
            <DatePicker {...this.props} />
          </View>
        </View>
        {touched && error &&
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 5 }}>
            <View style={[this.globalTheme.get('middleV'), { flex: 1 }]}>
                  {null}
                </View>
                <View style={[this.globalTheme.get('middleH'), { flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }]}>
                  <Icon name='error-outline' size={16} style={{ paddingRight: 10, color: '#db5454' }} />
                  <Text style={[
                    this.globalTheme.get('textRegular'),
                    { color: '#db5454', fontSize: 12 }
                  ]}>{error}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            }
          </View>
        );
      }
        case 'custom_shippingCharge': {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <Row>
              <Col size={50} style={[this.globalTheme.get('middleV')]}> //Line 373
                {this.props.label}
              </Col>
              <Col size={38} style={[touched && error ? this.formTheme.get('boxedRed') : this.formTheme.get('boxed')]}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                  <Input {...this.props} />
                </View>
              </Col>
              <Col size={2} />
              <Col size={10}>
                <View style={[this.globalTheme.get('middleV'), { flex: 1 }]}>
                  {this.props.button}
                </View>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            {touched && error &&
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 5 }}>
                <View style={[this.globalTheme.get('middleV'), { flex: 1 }]}>
                  {null}
                </View>
                <View style={[this.globalTheme.get('middleH'), { flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }]}>
                  <Icon name='error-outline' size={16} style={{ paddingRight: 10, color: '#db5454' }} />
                  <Text style={[
                this.globalTheme.get('textRegular'),
                { color: '#db5454', fontSize: 12 }
              ]}>{error}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
    }
}
```

[image]

Maybe someone can help me to give explanation about what the mean of this error and what caused that or give me advice about a way to upgrade react native project (that using typescript in code) from version 0.49 to latest version. 
Thank you very much..

Comment: hello, I have the same issue as you. Have you find solution for it? Please help me if you found. Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, that is because some library or dependencies is outdated version and still used React.PropTypes.
My first solution is update dependencies.
If that is not possible, I try to change React.PropTypes in that dependencies and project using PropTypes from prop-types dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

[Proptypes have been removed from React Native starting at React Native 0.47](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45602095/react-native-proptypes-has-been-moved-to-a-separate-package). You're using 0.49, which should already have given you the error, but perhaps you had not migrated React before?

Anyway, it looks like one or more of your components is using PropTypes. It doesn't seem like the problem is in `FieldValidation.tsx` itself; it might be on one of the components used by that file, including third-party components (in `node_modules`).

You need to either update the component to use [proper generic types for props](https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-render-props-in-typescript-b561b00bc67c), or (less advised) add the `PropTypes` library back and refer to that.

Comment: Yes, I had not migrated React before. In RN 0.49, I'm using react 16.0.0-alpha.12.